# C++/WinRT Hololens 2 - How to convert the position of an object from the device coordinate system to the world coordinate system

Tags: uwp, hololens, coordinate-systems, c++-winrt, windows-mixed-reality

I am having trouble getting the position of an object in world coordinates, using [TryGetTransformTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.perception.spatial.spatialcoordinatesystem.trygettransformto?view=winrt-22621).

The results are very incoherent.

**WHAT I AM DOING**

I understand that world coordinate system is the coordinate system of a spatial stationary frame set in the beginning of the program, as said in the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.perception.spatial.spatialstationaryframeofreference?view=winrt-22621).
The device coordinate system can be gotten thanks to an attached reference frame, which follows the device.

How I get the device coordinate system ( in **Update** function, so called each frame) :

```
HolographicFramePrediction prediction = holographicFrame.CurrentPrediction();
m_attachedReferenceFrame = m_spatialLocator.CreateAttachedFrameOfReferenceAtCurrentHeading();
SpatialCoordinateSystem deviceCoordinateSystem = m_attachedReferenceFrame.GetStationaryCoordinateSystemAtTimestamp(prediction.Timestamp());
```

m_spatialLocator is *SpatialLocator::GetDefault()*, set once at the beginning of the app,

How I get the world coordinate system (only once too)

```
m_stationaryReferenceFrame = m_spatialLocator.CreateStationaryFrameOfReferenceAtCurrentLocation();
m_worldCoordinateSystem = m_stationaryReferenceFrame.CoordinateSystem();
```

And finally, how I do the transform :

```
auto tryTransformMatrix = deviceCoordSystem.TryGetTransformTo(m_worldCoordinateSystem);
if (!tryTransformMatrix)
    return;
    
float4x4 transformMatrix = tryTransformMatrix.Value();
    
float3 devicePos = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f };
auto worldPos = transform(devicePos, transformMatrix);
```

devicePos is juste an simple example for testing, in practice there could be anything in its values.

The results are really wrong, if I don't move the Hololens *worldPos = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f }* (rounded up) so it's correct, if I rotate the device horizontaly it seems to stay correct but if I rotate horizontaly (for example, if the device is looking right at the sky), the results are wrong, the y coordinate does not move in worldPos.

Please keep in mind that devicePos is the position of an object IN the device coordinate system, so here the object is 1 meter in front of the Hololens, whatever orientation it has.

Do you have any ideas ? Thank you !

Comment: Does "if I rotate horizontaly (for example, if the device is looking right at the sky), the results are wrong, the y coordinate does not move in worldPos" mean that rotating the HoloLens device vertically will not affect the Y axis in the coordinate system? It is probably by design. Can you describe the behavior you expect? If you can provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we might be able to do some research.